# Masonry JS Margin Problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-masonry

need someone familiar with Masonry JS. I'm developing a site locally, and everything is fine. When I push to my live staging site, my Masonry items seem to ignore the bottom margin that I have.

See here: http://dev.benadelt.com

You can see that the right-most grid items are overlapping each other, and the rest of the grid items don't show the 35px bottom margin I have in the CSS so spacing is off. If you resize the browser so the grid re-adjusts, even if you then bring the browser back to full size, everything looks fine.

Also, on my local machine it all works just fine upon first page load.

Any ideas there? Thanks so much!

Ben

Answer (score 1):

AH figured it out. I had to use $(window).load rather than $(document).ready!